# Show attachment names as a coloumn in Sharepoint list - 2007

Tags: list, metadata, attachments

Is there a way I can show attachment names as a 'Title' field in SharePoint list 2007?

I'm wanting to save duplication having to type out the name of a file to show as the title in the list.

I've tried various formulas in the custom Title field list, but nothing is working. I don't have SharePoint designer.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Even if you do not have access to Designer (or Visual Studio obviously) it is still possible.

Take a look at the solution "[List all attachments when clicking the paperclip in a list view – updated version](http://spjsblog.com/2011/10/07/list-all-attachments-when-clicking-the-paperclip-in-a-list-view-updated-version/)", which displays the attachments when hovering over or clicking a paperclip next to the title.

It is not exactly what you ask for, but it may be good enough for you or you could modify it if you know how. it just uses javascript in a content editor webpart, so it is very easy to implement it.